# Javadoc comments formatting in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This might be heresy by some standards, but my eyes twitch when folded Javadoc comments are exactly one character out of line with the code. Like this:

```
/**
 * Standard Javadoc
 */
public void myawesomemethod()
{
    ...
}
```

How the comment appear when folded:

```
  * Standard Javadoc //  that extra space there makes me twitch!
 public void myawesomemethod()
 {
    ...
 }
```

Then:

```
/**
* Javadoc the way i have to write it to make it appear correct when folded
*/
public void myawesomemethod()
{
    ...
}
```

Appears this way:

```
 * Javadoc the way i have to write it to make it appear correct when folded
 public void myawesomemethod()
 {
    ...
 }
```

I was looking trough all the options in the code appearance profile, and it's not there AFAIK.

Does anyone have a trick to make Eclipse either format this the way i want it when folded, or perhaps make Eclipse use a different comment template (if possible) when generating comments?

Right now I have to change them all manually and if a were to import the code into another editor, it might even be reset trough a code-reformat :(

Comment: So your problem is the single leading space? One way (which might not what you want, though) would be to disable JavaDoc formatting completely (see your formatter settings).

Comment: My suggestion would be to avoid using folding. Instead, make use of the *Outline* view. Code folding may lead to confusion.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that single leading space. And I'd rather keep the Javadoc formatting too. (I am using it to autodocument the project, and i want to be able to customize that fully.)

GGrec: I am not sure I follow you. I don't see how to use that view to accomplish what I want. By outline view , i mean View->Outline and that shows class members and methods, and you can sort/hide/show various elements. (but nothing related to javadoc)